# How to check if lowercase letters exist?

Tags: python, string

I have been observing unusual behavior with the .`islower()` and `.isupper()` methods in Python.  For example:

```
>>> test = '8765iouy9987OIUY'
>>> test.islower()
False
>>> test.isupper()
False
```

However, the following mixed string value seems to work:

```
>>> test2 = 'b1'
>>> test2.islower()
True
>>> test2.isupper()
False
```

I do not understand this anomaly.  How can I detect lower case letters  as in `test`?

Comment: what anomaly? test is not upper nor lower, it is mixed. test2, on the other hand, contains only lower case *letters*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`islower()` and `isupper()` only return `True` if **all** letters in the string are lowercase or uppercase, respectively.

You'd have to test for individual characters; `any()` and a generator expression makes that relatively efficient:

```
>>> test = '8765iouy9987OIUY'
>>> any(c.islower() for c in test)
True
>>> any(c.isupper() for c in test)
True
```

Answer (score 6):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.2.1/lib/string-methods.html):

> islower()
>       Return true if all cased characters in the string are lowercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.
>
> isupper()
>       Return true if all cased characters in the string are uppercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.

To be more clear, both `"1".islower()` and `"1".isupper()` return `False`. If there is no cased letter, both function return false.

If you want to remove all the lowercase letters, you could:

```
>>> test = '8765iouy9987OIUY'
>>> "".join([i for i in test if not i.islower()])
'87659987OIUY'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) module:

```
import re
print re.findall(r"[a-z]",'8765iouy9987OIUY')
```

Output:

```
['i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
```

If there is no match, you will get `[]` as output. regular expression matches to all the characters from a to z.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could try `map()`:

```
map(str.isupper, '8765iouy9987OIUY')
# output: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
#         False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True]
```

And then use `any()` to check for any uppercase letters:

```
any(map(str.isupper, '8765iouy9987OIUY'))
# output: True
```

Answer (score 0):

For a password policy that requires at least 1 character that's upper, lower, and a digit. I think this is the most readable and straightforward approach.

```
def password_gen():
while True:
    password = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in range(12))
    tests = {}
    tests['upper'] = any(char.isupper() for char in password)
    tests['lower'] = any(char.islower() for char in password)
    tests['digit'] = any(char.isdigit() for char in password)
    if all(tests.values()):
        break
return password
```

Answer (score 0):

This can alternately be done as below:

```py
test = '8765iouy9987OIUY'
print(test == test.upper())  # returns False as some letters are small
test = '222WWWW'
print(test == test.upper())  # returns True as no letters are small
```